# 2015 Honda Fit LX, 20k miles, key will turn but engine will not always start on first try. Why?

Tags: honda, fit, ignition-switch

additionally, had oil changed at dealer two weeks ago, they installed a defective oil plug gasket/washer. caused the plug to spin and leak like it was stripped. but they said it was not stripped, it was the washer had bent. they fixed it and cleaned up the undercarriage. thankfully did not drive it without oil. the key/starter issue happened after the oil change. It's still under warranty. After the oil change problem don't want to go back to this dealer; another dealer is miles and miles further away. what could be the cause of the key not turning the car ignition on first try. Thank you.

Comment: Take it back to the dealer anyway. I understand your misgivings, but have them fix it. While they messed up the oil change, they did ultimately fix it. Even if they hadn't fixed it, they'd have ended up fixing it with a new motor in the end. Really, just take it to the dealership and have them deal with it.